# Normalize LastFM Tags

Tags: tags, last.fm, normalize

I have this set of music data crawled from LastFM, 

Now, I would like to normalize and classify the songs based on one tag per track. I got this master Genre list, https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=psnjFY3R2itsqjinSs9hkZw

But again, how will I identify, J-pop, JPop and Jap Pop all are same as Japanese Pop? Is there a web api or database which will be useful to get normalized genre?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

The tags on LastFM are given by users. Whom (what authority) do you expect to deliver a normalized view on these tags? I guess you can not expect such a service to exist.

Tags are a way to categorize information. You can not prevent users using different tags for the same meaning (e.g. as for japanese pop). If you want to normalize this then you would have to provide a normalization mapping on your own but then again you will not succeed as you would have to include all the new tags created. But how will you know what the different tags are for if the name is not self-explaining.

I suggest to go without a normalization and let the user decide what tags to search for. 
When listing songs show all tags don't try to show a normalized view.

Comment: Hi TheVjSen, if this helped you then please don't forget to vote. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for replying Michael. Yeah correct, I do not expect an authority or anything on the normalization of tags. What I asked for is according to some master list or some website, can we identify the relation between tags.